# Copy generated graph into another graph in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I want to copy a graph without some attributes. This is my code for generating the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx
from networkx.algorithms.community import LFR_benchmark_graph

n = [250, 500]
tau1 = 3
tau2 = 1.5
mu = 0.1
G = LFR_benchmark_graph(n[0], tau1, tau2, mu, average_degree=5,
                        min_community=20, seed=10)

gg=G.copy()   #Here I want to copy
networkx.drawing.draw(G)
```

This image is my `G` graph and when this graph copied to `gg`, I want to `gg` nodes haven't `community` feature and each node hasn't any feature.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from copy import deepcopy

gg = deepcopy(G)
```

Comment: Can you describe what happened? Does the problem stay equal?

Comment: Yes, result same to origin graph

Comment: Alternatively try writing the graph into a pickle and reading it into another new object. See [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.gpickle.html). And the next doc pages about read an write. I'm afraid I can't help more.